# A word meaning "a student who is repeating a class or grade"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word in English for a student who is repeating a grade at school or a (university) student who hasn't completed a mandatory course successfully the first time and is retaking the class?

Comment: I would hazard to guess that folks tend to tiptoe around terms for this, as saying someone has "flunked" a class or grade is pejorative.  You'll most likely hear a flock of nebulous terms which obfuscate the situation rather than specify it.

Comment: There can be a lot of reasons for failing a class. It shouldn't always sound pejorative. Maybe a bright student had an accident and spent too much time in the hospital which kept him from attending class.

Comment: "retained student" seems the usual term, at least in this academic paper https://direct.mit.edu/edfp/article/12/3/312/10274/Don-t-Hold-Back-The-Effect-of-Grade-Retention-on

Answer (score 3):

I already heard the term **holdback** used for "repeater."

hold back: (idiomatic) to delay, especially in school. *He's a year older than his classmates because he was held back in second grade* ([**Your Dictionary**](http://www.yourdictionary.com/hold-back#dXRAHSMDJod7sPPS.99))

> **Middle School Holdbacks Banned from Athletic Participation**
>
> *Last week, the Kentucky Board of Education approved a new statewide rule recommended by the Kentucky High School Athletic Association that, beginning in the 2015-2016 school year, middle school students who repeat a grade for any reason won't be able to play on a school athletic team in the year they are repeating.* ([**BlueGrassPreps**](http://bluegrasspreps.com/ky-boys-basketball/middle-school-holdbacks-276360.html))

Comment: The definition you cited is for the verb form thus the noun is ostensibly a neologism. Citing one article from Kentucky hardly validates the term as a standard usage in English which as I have been told is required for any answer around here.

Comment: I checked all the major dictionaries offered on the first page of Google and none provide a definition for ‘holdback’ as a noun. Merriam-Webster does refer to the verb form holding back a grade. Thus the noun form appears to be a neologism that is the furthest along in potentially being established as standard English, but not yet standard usage. My problem with it is that the term has a much more common meaning about held back funds which may cause confusion. A more coherent neologism might end up as the standard usage.

Answer (score 1):

**repeater** (n.)

> *Education* (originally and chiefly U.S.). A student who undertakes a grade or course again.
>
> 1909   *Cleveland Public Schools Ann. Rep.* 32   Dr. Ayres affirms
> that every sixth child in the elementary schools of American cities of
> size is a ‘repeater’.
>
> 2004   *Washington Post* (Nexis) 12 May a1   Many of the repeaters had
> failed English, which students must pass before they become
> 10th-graders. OED

> A student enrolled in a class or course for a second or subsequent
> time. [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repeater)

---

> In the recovery system at my school, I teach the ninth-grade
> **repeaters** English 9 every day for the first and second quarters. If they pass the class during the first and second quarters, they are
> eligible to take English 10 during the third and fourth quarters. If
> they pass both English 9 and 10 through the system, they will have
> recovered two English credits in one year. [Gary Hughes; *Powerful
> Language for Reluctant Learners*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22two%20repeaters%20in%20my%20class%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvIWY4cHQfHHU1Bf4MjSOhyopF-OxQ%3A1640702906329&ei=uiPLYd_FE8GYwbkP3uKOmAM&ved=0ahUKEwjfiqfP3ob1AhVBTDABHV6xAzMQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22two%20repeaters%20in%20my%20class%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQ6AdY5BlgjB1oAHAAeACAAViIAdEDkgEBNpgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books) (2020)

> Two of my classes had several **repeaters** in them, and I wouldn't
> have known this fact; except the teacher made it public knowledge
> because he couldn't control them at the time. My thoughts were, "God
> why are you punishing me? First, you did not allow me to become gifted
> and now you have me in a class with misfits?"  [Jane Green; *Life*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Life_the_Gift_That_Keeps_on_Giving/-cc-DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=two%20repeaters%20in%20my%20class&pg=PT34&printsec=frontcover)
> (2017)

Answer (score 1):

the used expression in this case is "resitter" for the students who fail in one class or more in the first sitting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I propose a neologism:

remediatee

remediate + -ee (from remedial education)

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ee

re·me·di·al
/rəˈmēdēəl/
adjective: remedial

```
giving or intended as a remedy or cure.
"remedial surgery"
    provided or intended for students who are experiencing learning difficulties.
    "remedial education"
```

Comment: Hello, Shelby. The 'U' in ELU is for (standard English) usage/[/s]. DIY proposals are specifically off-topic, as not being endorsable. Please delete, or I will have to downvote.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would prefer the conformance police downvote than to remove my creativity. I really don’t care about my stats. Maybe you can take me down below 100 as a remedial action to punish me for not complying? As if any of the answers were standard usage, lol. There doesn’t exist a standard term for the question. Duh.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I upvoted you for the civility of commenting to explain your future downvote.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth again I suggest you must be consistent and downvote all the answers here. Please read the comments I have added under the other answers explaining why they have provided neologisms not yet substantiated to be standard English usage.

Comment: You appreciate politeness. That would include non-violation of site regulations, when they're there for a clearly sound reason. ELU attempts to build up a searchable bank of standard usages, with rationales where possible. Creative suggestions, while far from being wrong per se, do not fit with the ELU model and could be taken as being acceptable when they are in fact unidiomatic. This would not be helpful to those using ELU as a benchmark. There are many websites devoted to creative writing, poetry, innovative wordplay ....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth until I see consistency in your application of the site regulations by applying the same standard to the other answers, then I must presume there’s no coherent application of the claimed regulation.

Comment: I can't address every question / answer. Perhaps a little more help, as here ...? One Qn addressed; one I'm still looking at for idiomaticity (ELU expects _some_ reasonable research, not a thesis). // I've found a fair few tokens of 'holdback/s' in this sense, one in scare-quotes. It's not DIY. But "I propose a neologism ..." (meaning a candidate not in the lexis) is not what ELU expects.

Comment: This isn't a neologism. Google finds quite a number of academic references which use it (although not in this sense, admittedly).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Wikipedia defines neologism, _‘A neologism is a relatively recent or isolated term, word, or phrase that may be in the process of entering common use, but that has not been fully accepted ...’_. Frankly you guys are so nitpicky that it makes contributing to this site not very enjoyable. Language is not as precise and static as control freaks ostensibly wish it was. I enjoy Urban Dictionary. In real life adaptivity and creativity trumps captivity and banal librarians.